# C# linq xml missing element gives throws exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq

What I am trying to get is a list or array of values for each of an element.

But if the child element is missing, I would like to get an empty string.

This is what I have as a code, but when the child `x` is missing it does not return `""` but throws an IllegalOperation exception:

```
var firstphs = xliff.Descendants()
                    .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                    .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                    .Elements(xmlns+ "mrk")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
                    .Select(e => e.Elements(xmlns+"x").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("id").Value ?? "")
                    .ToArray();
```

Can somebody point out what is wrong in the code and how to correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing attribute in case `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` would cause exception. You can try this way instead :

```
var firstphs = xliff.Descendants()
                    .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                    .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                    .Elements(xmlns+ "mrk")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
                    .Select(e => e.Elements(xmlns+"x").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("id")).FirstOrDefault())
                    .ToArray();
```

General useful tip : avoid using `Value` property in case an element or attribute may not exists. Instead, cast the element or attribute to `string`, as demonstrated in the above snippet.

Comment: Perfect! I knew a `Select` was missing... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#6, you can do this:

```
var firstphs = xliff.Descendants()
                    .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                    .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                    .Elements(xmlns+ "mrk")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
                    .Select(e => e.Elements(xmlns+"x").FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("id").Value ?? "")
                    .ToArray();
```

Note the `?.` after `FirstOrDefault()`. It's called the "null propagation operator" and it will return null whenever the expression to the left is null. If not, it will continue evaluating the expression.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a list of compiler errors. (I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2013).

Comment: C# 6 is supported in Visual Studio 2015 and later